# Your ideal platform for a high db, scalable site?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mongodb, scalability

What would you consider to be an ideal solution for a new service with the following needs?

1. Easy to hire new talent
2. Fast and scalable databases (easy to scale to TB when needed, read and write heavy)
3. Secure in itself for when bugs happen
4. Easy to debug and understand for new programmers joining the team

CodeIgniter we're fairly keen on but in terms of template engines and database needs, we're exploring options and would love any experienced insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mongo at my first development job. The learning curve isn't too steep since almost every dev already has some background in js.

Answer (score 0):

Every framework claims to be scalable. If you have tables up to 30 million rows, I'd definitely go for Ruby on Rails or Django. These are really rapid web development frameworks. Easy to debug and easy to learn.
I'm not sure about really large databases though. In that case you'll have to think about database design carefully, and then choose a framework to develop on top of that database. MySQL and PostgreSQL are the obvious alternatives. Then think about programming. Don't rely on any framework for huge databases.